What is the best way to create a list of lists of multiple dataframes?
These are my DataFrames:
import pandas as pd 
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 2, 3], 'b': [4, 5, 6]})
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 2, 3], 'b': [4, 5, 6]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 2, 3], 'b': [4, 5, 6]})
df3 = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 2, 3], 'b': [4, 5, 6]})
df4 = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 2, 3], 'b': [4, 5, 6]})
df5 = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 2, 3], 'b': [4, 5, 6]})
df6 = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 2, 3], 'b': [4, 5, 6]})
df7 = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 2, 3], 'b': [4, 5, 6]})
df8 = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 2, 3], 'b': [4, 5, 6]})
df9 = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 2, 3], 'b': [4, 5, 6]})
df10 = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1,2, 3], 'b': [4, 5, 3]})

And the expected output is to create a list of lists using these dataframes.
out = [
    [df, df1, df2, df3], 
    [df4, df5, df6, df7],
    [df8, df9, df10]
]

This is what I have tried so far. But in the final loop where I need to get the dataframe in order to run my functions, the names of column changes into numbers:
l_0 = [df, df1, df2, df3, df4, df5, df6, df7, df8, df9, df10]
s = np.array_split(l_0, 3)

for chunck in s:
    for g in chunck:
        df = pd.DataFrame(g)
        print(df)

 #output
           0  1
        0  1  4
        1  2  5
        2  3  6

